# configure openldap to return results to this filter: (&(&(givenName>=0)(givenName<=zz))(|(givenName=user*)(sn=user*)))

Tags: ubuntu, openldap

I have old openldap server version 2.4.23 which we need to upgrade to version 2.5.14, everything is working perfectly fine untill i try to search using this filter:

```
(&(&(givenName>=0)(givenName<=zz))(|(givenName=user*)(sn=user*)))
```

how can i allow openldap to return results based on this filter, keep in mind that i can't modify the client filter query, the only part that changes is the username part

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we need to add ORDERING caseIgnoreOrderingMatch to the givenName and sn attributes